# Are there brokers or companies who trade Forex and make money for us on our investment? And do you think fxtradeinvestment is legit?

Tags: foreign-exchange, broker, fraud, scams, online-brokerage

So I was looking for some extra income and think forex is a good way to earn a little extra money.

I want to know whether there are companies or brokers who trade forex for us and pay us on our investment.

One such company I found out on Craiglist is www.fxtradeinvestment.com.

They pay $5000 on $500 in 14 days and $10000 on $1000 in 14 days. Do you think this can be true because as soon as you search the company's name in Google, you can find forexfraud.com as the 4th website in the Google result. So I thought this company must have had bad results paying customers in past. In short, do you think this is legit?

New Edit - As on Aug. 10 I found out that this broker is a scam and non one should continue with their services.
You can read about them on rip off report.

http://www.ripoffreport.com/r/FX-PRO-INVESTMENT-AND-ECOMONEY/internet/FX-PRO-INVESTMENT-AND-ECOMONEY-GARRETH-PILKINGTON-VIRGINA-LEGERE-OF-NEWTON-MAINETHESE-A-1216209

Comment: it's utter nonsense.  just a straightforward scam.

Comment: @JoeBlow   How can be so sure about it.

Comment: It's so **utterly ridiculous** it's not worth discussing.  Pick up the phone and call the "number" on the "web site". It's not even a *registered business*.  For goodness sake.  Flag it to "craig's list" and they'll delete it.

Comment: From their testimonials page on the website, three out of four of them mention that "this looks like a scam but totally isn't". The lady doth protest too much methinks, as they say.

Comment: "forex is a good way to earn a little extra money." {citation needed}

Answer (score 13):

So you think there is a business that can take $X and in two weeks turn it into $10X plus their profit.

That means that in two weeks you can turn $1,000 into $10,000. So every two weeks you add a zero, in six weeks you add 3 zeros. In 12 weeks total your $1,000 is now $1,000,000,000; and in a few weeks after that you are richer than Bill Gates.

All Guaranteed!

**Run away.**

Answer (score 0):

There are legitimate multi currency mutual funds/efts.

But I don't think their rate of return will produce the extra money you're looking for any faster than any other kind of investment with comparable risks. To make money fast, you have to accept nontrivial risk of losing money fast, which isn't what you seem to have in mind.